# EntityFrameworkCore: How to initialize a Database and seed it the first time user uses an application

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have build a project using Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 and EntityFrameworkCore.

I have seed manually a couple of dummy data and I was developing my solution. Now, I want to deploy the in the server, but I get the problem that by starting the application the first time, it crash since it does not find a data base and data.

I have googled and I find the solution for Visual Studio 2013 and previous using the **CreateDatabaseIfNotExists** class that need the package: **System.Data.Entity**
(http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx), however, such classes and packages do not exist in EntityFrameworkCore.

How does I create and populate a database with at least one row if user is using my application by the first time in EntityFrameworkCore?

or which is the equivalent to **System.Data.Entity** in Entity Framework Core?

Comment: Is the connection string correct?

Comment: Yes, it work in my local development computer. But when trying to start the project in another computer, it crash because the getall method does not find any database.
I need to create a database the first time somebody uses the app or move to another computer.
So, I need something like CREATEDATABASEIFDOESNOTEXISTS class that initialize a DB in case first time use

Comment: Yeah, I figure the connection string is correct on *your* computer, obviously not on the server. Where is the server supposed to create the database? That information should be in its connection string.

Answer (score 3):

Rowan Miller [says](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/629#issuecomment-114729604) that `ApplyMigrations` is enough to create database (if not exist) and apply all (nesessary) migrations.

Create method like this:

```
public void CreateDbAndSampleData(IServiceProvider applicationServices)
{
    using (var serviceScope = applicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
    {
        using (var db = serviceProvider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>()) 
        {
            // This will [try to] create database
            // and apply all necessary migrations
            db.Database.AsRelational().ApplyMigrations();

            // then you can check for existing data and modify something
            var admin = db.Users.Where(x => x.Name == "Superadmin").FirstOrDefault();
            if (admin == null)
            {
                db.Users.Add(new User {...});
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And call it from your `Startup.cs`, at end of `Configure` method:

```
CreateDbAndSampleData(app.ApplicationServices);
```

This code will run on every app startup, so you need to be accurate and do not overwrite any non-critical data changes (like changing Users's comment etc)

You can use `MusicStore` app as a sample: [Startup.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/blob/dev/samples/MusicStore/Startup.cs#L211) and [SampleData.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/blob/dev/samples/MusicStore/Models/SampleData.cs)

Comment: I am actually greatful that EF Core doesn't attempt to create the Db itself. You have to intentionally tell it to and that you can safely rely on the fact that you need to run the migrations first before your app will work.